# Зависимость числа параметров конструктора и функции шаблонного класса от аргумента шаблона

Tags: c++, ооп, шаблоны-с++

Задачка: сделать класс многомерной матрицы с обобщенным конструктором, в который поступает заданное аргументом шаблона N количество переменных, определяющих размерность каждого измерения, и обобщенной функцией индексирования по этим N измерениям.

Так я реализовал класс матрицы:

```
template <typename T, unsigned N>
class Grid final
{
public:
    T * data;
    unsigned * sizes;

    Grid(size_type * sizes, T const &t) : sizes(sizes)
    {
        size_type data_size = 1;
        for (auto i = N; i > 0; i--)
            data_size *= size;
        data = new T[data_size];
        for (auto it = data, end = data + data_size; it != end; ++it)
            *it = t;
    }
};
```

Вот вроде такого конструктора и функции требуется в задаче:

```
template <typename T, unsigned N>
class Grid final
{
public:
    Grid(..., T const & t) : Grid<(...).size()>({...},t) {} //... - size1, size2, ..,sizeN

    T & operator()(...) //... - i1, i2, ..,iN
    {
        return data[i1*sizes[0] + i2*sizes[1] + ... + iN*sizes[N-1];
    }
};

int main()
{
    
    Grid<float, 3> const g3(2, 3, 4, 1.0f);
    assert(1.0f == g3(1, 1, 1));
    Grid<float, 2> g2(2, 5, 2.0f);
    assert(2.0f == g2(1, 1));
    return 0;
}
```

Понятно, что  `...` работает совсем не так, его вставил для примера.

Можно ли вообще инструментами c++ реализовать такой конструктор? Буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: [конструктор](https://github.com/kokkos/mdspan/blob/760060059fb746018a9849234e02dc9bf003861b/include/experimental/__p0009_bits/mdspan.hpp#L148), [индекс](https://github.com/kokkos/mdspan/blob/760060059fb746018a9849234e02dc9bf003861b/include/experimental/__p0009_bits/mdspan.hpp#L248).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это сделать можно, достаточно сделать конструктор шаблоном и добавить пару проверок:

```
#include <array>
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstddef>

template <typename T, unsigned N>
class Grid final
{
public:
    ::std::unique_ptr<T []> m_p_data;
    ::std::array<unsigned, N> m_sizes;

    template<typename... x_SizePack> explicit
    Grid(T const & t, x_SizePack... size_pack) : m_p_data{}, m_sizes{size_pack...}
    {
        static_assert(N == sizeof...(x_SizePack));
        static_assert((::std::is_same<unsigned, x_SizePack>::value && ...));
        ::std::size_t const size{(static_cast<::std::size_t>(size_pack) * ...)};
        m_p_data.reset(new T [size]);
        T * const p_begin{m_p_data.get()};
        T * const p_end{p_begin + size};
        T * p_item{p_begin};
        for (;;)
        {
            *p_item = t;
            ++p_item;
            if (p_end == p_item)
            {
                break;
            }
            continue;
        }
        return;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Grid<int, 3> gr{42, 3u, 4u, 4u};
    return 0;
}
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGISQBspK4AMngMmAByPgBGmMQSAMykAA6oCoRODB7evv5BaRmOAmER0SxxCVzJdpgOWUIETMQEOT5%2BgbaY9sUMjc0EpVGx8Um2TS1teZ0KE4PhwxWj1QCUtqhexMjsHOaJ4cjeWADUJoluzcRMAJ5n2CYaAIJ7B0eYp%2BdsLCS3ifdPLwYhy8JzObgI1xSmAA%2BgQroQFHcHs8zPsgW8Pm5kLN0FgqEiAU8CJgWCkDMTMRCocw2McACqkY5eBgZYARdDHSIEx6HJgKBTHADixDwHJozFoyJMAHYrE8Ul4YrQ8MgQMjjhrjiAQDjtcy8ABHLwwlJwsF004AVisloAIndjixoSloegmE0znLHpqtTqCOhtZcbmDmaz2YyuX9HdCMgAvTCIxJe9Wa4mk8mYMFUxisTAAOgLx1U0KEeHjyiYyAA1g7MKoySrCCmNcLRRALWgWQRTmYAscCIzi6Xy5WqwW88c4ybRystdGXW6PbKZbbGU6p4jZVPnaPxyvm6dl08fT7Zu6VdC%2BUoWhBIh97YlbZOy5hUFRxxAhy%2BK9WVitPQep5NI4yCXvy8QEFA2q6iAeAKDGuYhiyeBspg6CDiW36jnc2oAG5iMaPYBOYfbjn%2BAHHieGrQf60EvrCxydrMz7xjKFgQGeIHQqIsxgjRAY6vRBB3Bx9EpDOxwAFTHGR%2B5JoBmpOgu7pMHmxAJpgkERAA7vSVoWFOJh2v%2B8mUVRFrSUx3YunEwDhGxSmuipebAJpED/tKD5elRGoWYxAjMS6rhsTZmB2QwPYWCxmaeRR3o%2BX5LqECSIXQrZ9mxaZ8VUfwxDHBAAFJv%2BZknmxClUZJSVpve/ZxT5pWWNYVUpVl9U%2BngVD5UFDAcmcD5Ps1LDFdlbVlSVbWajE6lMDWrUTYe9rjT5naOAwxp1T5%2B5LRq6kEJsDAbRqW3PJlyZPOE3YsEw4TuVKR4ja26BghdjKJA6wDEGxkhmK9XiMpIf3HADcneZqu37ccGhxcdHBrLQnCWrwfgcFopCoJwbjWNYk4bFs7x7DwpAEJosNrFWICWho%2BicJISMk2jnC8AoIBU8TKOw6QcCwDAiAoKgpJ0PE5CUGgAv0AkwBcGYP00LQxLEMzEAxPTMThM01ycITotsIIADyDC0Br7OkFgV1GOIxv4Op9S4Qm9N1nUXjEprvAXd09PKlN6seFg9NwngLAu2sVAGMACgAGp4Jg2m69SLsyIIIhiOwUgJ/IShqPTuhcPohjGFjlj6HgMTM5AayoKaWTMxwAC0Nc4n1piNZYZgaMcNcAOpiLQ7cd3WcJML3UJuoIKq9/ExAkEz3R1L0Lg9VMfg56ECzlJUeiFJkAiLxv6RbwwQxr8sXQ9A0cw7zntT1AI/QtIfIxVOMAwX0/d%2Brw/EhrAouPbHocKYDsHgcMEZ02NujDgqgAAcAQa4BEkMcYAyBkDHClnmMw%2BVMbNxsMcXAhASA9kSDnY4HgxbxAIVwFYvA2ZaD/KQcmlNqYcFpqQQODDkao3AUzFmRMSZrC5rzDYBAFQDgoBAUWKRBbEEiLmTgUCYFwIQUglBZg0G8DQngkUAYc78ETqIcQqcdHpxUOoY22dSDaSuCkIOjDEakHYbwcBusnbCOOG%2BIs0DYHwMQcg1B6CIAkIkeLchlCeHs1oQgTATAsAJHcow5hrCqb2IZhwLhrNeFkwplTeGHBEigI4YzUJNDgEcDMHkhxBTqGk1ILbBWWR/BAA%3D)

Как альтернатива, можно выделить тип для индексирования и передавать везде его:

```
    using t_Index = ::std::array<unsigned, N>;

    t_Index m_sizes;

    Grid(T const & t, t_Index const & sizes) : m_p_data{}, m_sizes{sizes}
```